# Display valid msg to user for org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I m new to Springs, Hibernate and REST API.

How can i catch `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` ( I do not want to delete the mill data since you have dependent(child) data on the mill and display a appropriate msg to user that it cannot delete it due to orders exists for the mill.

Please Help.

Thank you

Here is my Code.

### MillResource.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mills/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteMill(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to delete Mill : {}", id);
    millRepository.delete(id);
    log.debug(" ", id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert("mill", id.toString())).build();
}
```

CrudRepository

```
void delete(ID id);

/**
 * Deletes a given entity.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
 */
```

HeaderUtil.java

```
public class HeaderUtil {

    public static HttpHeaders createAlert(String message, String param) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("X-omsApp-alert", message);
        headers.add("X-omsApp-params", param);
        return headers;
    }

    public static HttpHeaders createEntityCreationAlert(String entityName, String param) {
        return createAlert("A new " + entityName + " is created with identifier " + param, param);
    }

    public static HttpHeaders createEntityUpdateAlert(String entityName, String param) {
        return createAlert("A " + entityName + " is updated with identifier " + param, param);
    }

    public static HttpHeaders createEntityDeletionAlert(String entityName, String param) {
        return createAlert("A " + entityName + " is deleted with identifier " + param, param);
    }

    public static HttpHeaders createFailureAlert(String entityName, String errorKey, String defaultMessage) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("X-omsApp-error", defaultMessage);
        headers.add("X-omsApp-params", entityName);
        return headers;
    }
}
```

Mill.java

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Objects;

    /**
     * A Mill.
     */

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "mill")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Mill implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "code", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Addresses addresses;

    @OneToOne
    private NoteSet notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mill")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Price> pricess = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mill")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<Quality> qualitiess = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mill")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<SimpleGsmShade> simpleGsmShadess = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mill")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<CustomerGroup> groupss = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mill")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<DerivedGsmShade> derivedGsmShadess = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Addresses getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Addresses addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public NoteSet getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(NoteSet noteSet) {
        this.notes = noteSet;
    }

    public Set<Price> getPricess() {
        return pricess;
    }

    public void setPricess(Set<Price> prices) {
        this.pricess = prices;
    }

    public List<Quality> getQualitiess() {
        return qualitiess;
    }

    public void setQualitiess(List<Quality> qualitys) {
        this.qualitiess = qualitys;
    }

    public Set<SimpleGsmShade> getSimpleGsmShadess() {
        return simpleGsmShadess;
    }

    public void setSimpleGsmShadess(Set<SimpleGsmShade> simpleGsmShades) {
        this.simpleGsmShadess = simpleGsmShades;
    }

    public Set<CustomerGroup> getGroupss() {
        return groupss;
    }

    public void setGroupss(Set<CustomerGroup> customerGroups) {
        this.groupss = customerGroups;
    }

    public Set<DerivedGsmShade> getDerivedGsmShadess() {
        return derivedGsmShadess;
    }

    public void setDerivedGsmShadess(Set<DerivedGsmShade> derivedGsmShades) {
        this.derivedGsmShadess = derivedGsmShades;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Mill mill = (Mill) o;
        if(mill.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, mill.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mill{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", code='" + code + "'" +
            ", name='" + name + "'" +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a try-catch block in the controller, catch the exception, and in the exception, you can do whatever action you want. Show some other page, display error, etc. You can add errors with model.addAttribute. Pass Model model  as input parameter to the controller method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to handle the Exception. Introduce a try catch block and output the appropriate message.

Handle the exception at the base level and funnel it to the controller.